# What should be specified as the second argument of useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Is there any point in specifying a second argument to useEffect, such as a function that never changes?

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const dispatch(asyncTestFunction({ data }))
  },
  [data, dispatch],
);
```

In this case, why do we put dispatch as the second argument?

The documentation states that it is not necessary to include functions such as useState.

https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation might be like this ,

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

//Effect to dispatch action to redux store

useEffect(
  () => {
     dispatch(asyncTestFunction({ data }))
  },
  [data, dispatch],
);
```

Here the linter(eslint) is satisfied as you are adding `dispatch` to deps array.
The linter doesn't know whether the dispatch reference will remain the same or change in subsequent renders, even though it is stable since the store was created.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am convinced.

Answer (score 0):

Those `[data, dispatch]` are called dependencies not arguments, which means your `useEffect` is dependent on them changing for it to be triggered.

Leave the array `[]` empty, your `useEffect` will be called only when the page loads. In your case you can use only `[data]` so that when data changes your `useEffect` is triggered.

You don't need to add functions as dependencies because that may cause the `useEffect` to be called infinitely.

Think of it like this "when `data` changes I want to `dispatch`" but if I say "when `dispatch` changes I wanna `dispatch` again". See how that can cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am convinced.